# Flex - does anyone have an example of the use of the VideoDisplay control events

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, videodisplay

The Flex 3 docs are fairly basic. Can someone post a more complete example that uses the control's events? I'm still trying to get my head around ActionScript events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find an interesting article concerning stateChange & playheadUpdate events on http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/01/determining-a-videodisplay-controls-current-playback-state-using-the-state-property-and-statechange-event/

For a more complex example, take a look at the [FXVideo component](http://www.fxcomponents.com/flex-video-player/) source code (in main unit FXVideo.as).